# after_create called after failed saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to send request to external software whenever I am certain that a model is saved.

1) How do I determine the order in which after_create is called?

2) does it get called on a failed create?

The RAILS API documentation says:

> Note that this callback is still wrapped in the transaction around save.

3) Does this mean it requires the `save` to be successful before `after_save` is called or does it mean that once `save` is called `after_save` is always triggered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How would I learn in what order after_create is called and if it
>   persists through a failed create?

You can read the order of callbacks here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

If the transaction fails, the `save` event (and `create`/`update` events) return `false`. This will stop all later callbacks from being run. So, `after_save`, `after_create`/`after_update` all never get run on a failed `save` (or on a failed `create`/`update`).

...and the transaction gets rolled back so the database is not actually updated.